# R openxlsx error using "loadWorkbook": WARNING: simpleWarning in unzip(file, exdir = xmlDir): error 1 in extracting from zip file

Tags: r, openxlsx

Attempting to load data from an Excel spreadsheet in R using `openxlsx`, I get the following error/warning,

`WARNING: simpleWarning in unzip(file, exdir = xmlDir): error 1 in extracting from zip file.  This is not a zipped file.`

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is not related to zip-issues.  Instead, this is probably a file-lock error.  Check to be certain that the workbook in question is not currently open.  If so, close it and try again.